# How to close the Alert or Pop up displaying on the mobile using Selenium Android Driver?

Tags: android, mobile, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am Automating a Web Application in Android Mobile using Android WebDriver, But I am having a problem closing the Alert OR Pop Up Window.

I am just navigating to my apps url(http://m.url.com) and it shows a Alert/Pop Up window asking me to download the Native app and things like that and I am unable to close this Alert OR Pop up with selenium as I am not able to find the elements of Close button and other buttons on the Alert OR Pop up..

This Alert or Pop up does not display on system but only displays in Mobile..

Please suggest some solution this problem.. Thanks

Comment: Did you try webdriver.switchTo().alert()?

Comment: @A.J:Yes I tried with driver.SwitchTo().Alert()... also but of no help..

Comment: After trying hard for so long finally got rid of this thing.
I used driver.SwitchTo().activeElement().click; I dont know where it is clicking but the alert is closed after this line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Alert or Pop-Up displaying was an interstitial ad. 
Using **http://myurl.com/?interstitial=false**, This alert or pop-up will not display..

Comment: please can you explain more? i would like to disable popup from appium